# I'm having issues with subroutines inside of __getitem__()

Tags: python, class, subroutine

I have created a piece of code in python which makes use of the **getitem** subroutine, which I am not too familiar with.
Inside the **getitem** subroutine, there are multiple subroutines, one of which is:

```
def load(self,i):
    return str(i)
```

However when I try to call it elsewhere in the project...

```
self.load(x)
```

... it says that it cannot find the subroutine:

```
self.load(x)
AttributeError: 'Calc' object has no attribute 'load'
```

I have tried using

```
self.__getitem__.load(x)
```

but that doesn't work either.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Usually (never?) you don't call a method using self. You should create an instance of the class, and use the instance to call the method

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In python, it's not usual to refer to subroutines; _functions_ are used or, if the function is bound to and object, methods. It would help if you provided a [mcve] showing enough code to reproduce the issue including how you're defining the class and how you are calling the method in question

Comment: Which class has the `load()` method?

Comment: the load() method is in the default constructor of the same class as  __getitem__()